# assign entire column to a string variable using VBA

Tags: vba

There is any possibility to store an entire column in a string variable?
I need that variable as a string and not range type.
I mean, something like this:

```
    Dim myStrVar As String
    myStrVar = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
    MsgBox myStrVar
```

This code error is: Type mismatch
I want to specify that my column contains only text (string type).

If possible, how can I do this?? Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  A `Range` is a series of cells with values so it makes sense you cant just assign them to a string since there is more than one (possibly over a million cells in 1 column depending on you version of Excel).  Are you trying to concatenate the values of every cell?

Comment: @psubsee2003: I want to use all the cells information from that column to send an email with that information. So I need that variable that will be my email message. And yes, I want to concatenate all the cells content and store it in a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
a = 2
do while cells(a,1)<>""
mystrvar = mystrvar & cells(a,1)
a = a +1
msgbox mystrvar
loop
```